# Continuity of roots of a polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider a polynomial  $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ of degree $2$ with $a,b,c$ coming from $\Bbb R$. Now as the value of constant $'a'$ changes continuously, will the root of $p(x)$ also change continuously?

I think it will. If someone can prove or disprove it.

Edit:Can someone give some intutive proof for a general n degree polynomial?

Comment: _Yes..._ provided you consider complex roots too.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel can you please give a proof.

Comment: I only meant that as a comment, not a statement!

Comment: Be careful...to see what I mean consider what happens if $b = 0$, and $a$ goes from positive to negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are considering complex roots that is true. Loosely speaking, if the distance between $(a,b,c)$ and $(a',b',c')$ is small (say, $\leq \varepsilon$) by evaluating $a'x^2+b'x+c'$ at the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ we get something small ($\leq K\varepsilon$), so the roots of $a'x^2+b'x+c'$ cannot be too far from the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$. Indeed this argument is simple to turn into a rigorous one (by the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)) if the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ are simple (no pun intended). If there are multiple roots (that happens when the discriminant is zero) a bit of extra care is needed. For instance, if for a quadratic real polynomial the term $b^2-4ac$ goes from being positive to being negative, the roots go from being real to being complex.

Comment: Very nice explanation sir. Can it be generalized for any n degree polynomial? If possible can you please give a similar proof for it.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: assuming that $a\neq 0$ then observe that

$$ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x+\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)\left(x+\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)$$